# immutable _id error when performing MongoDB bulkWrite replaceOne on first attempt only

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm working on a little web application that will crawl and update baseball standings by day and track teams positions (among other things) over time.

I have an API I grab all of this from and a collection in MongoDB that stores all the team data and information for the current day. Right now I just run this manually but eventually it'll be automated to run at like 3am or whenever.

The API supplies a unique ID for each team that never changes. So what I'm doing is I'm taking in the team data from the API. Passing it to a function that then extracts the teams data (there is other data from the response object I don't need), puts it into an object for replacement, and then wherever that team ID exist in the collection its document is replaced in a bulkWite.

```
async function currentStandings(db,team_standings,callback){
  const current_standings = db.collection('current_standings');

  let replacePool = [];

  for(const single_team of team_standings.data.standing){
    let replaceOnePusher = {
      replaceOne: {
        "filter": {"team_id": single_team.team_id},
        "replacement": single_team
      }
    }

    replacePool.push(replaceOnePusher);
  }

  await current_standings.bulkWrite(replacePool);

  callback();
}
```

However when I execute this code for the first time each day I get an error reading `BulkWriteError: After applying the update, the (immutable) field '_id' was found to have been altered to _id: ObjectId('5f26e57b6831761ac840bf1d')` (not the same ID every day) and if I look in Compass the data isn't updated. If I immediately run the script again, it goes through successfully without error. Refreshing the data in compass generates the correct data.

Can someone explain to me what is going wrong here? This is actually my first time using MongoDB since I wanted to learn it and this pet project seemed like a good place to start.